# hibernate nested select parameter

Tags: hibernate, seam

I have a hibernate query with a nested select:

```
((EntityManager)Component.getInstance("entityManager")).createQuery("SELECT e FROM someEntity e " +
                "WHERE e.field1 = ?1 AND e.field2 IS NOT NULL AND " +
                "e.field3 IN " +
                "(SELECT t.field3 from otherEntity t " +
                "WHERE t.id.field4 = ?2 " +
                "AND t.field5 > 0 " +
                "AND t.field6 != 'SUBMITTED')")
                .setParameter(1, processor.ONE_PARAM)
                .setParameter(2, processor.OTHER_PARAM)
                                .getResultList();
```

If I run this query as is, I get no errors or warnings and no results(returns null).  If I change the query by replacing the 2nd parameter with the hardcoded value I get the results I expect:

```
((EntityManager)Component.getInstance("entityManager")).createQuery("SELECT e FROM someEntity e " +
                "WHERE e.field1 = ?1 AND e.field2 IS NOT NULL AND " +
                "e.field3 IN " +
                "(SELECT t.field3 from otherEntity t " +
                "WHERE t.id.field4 = hardcoded_other_param " +
                "AND t.field5 > 0 " +
                "AND t.field6 != 'SUBMITTED')")
                .setParameter(1, processor.ONE_PARAM)
                                .getResultList();
```

The outer and nested query work separately and together correctly in Oracle.  Do params not work in Hibernate nested selects or am I missing something?

I'm using hibernate 3.31 with JSF 1.2 and Seam 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run the debugger and check what the query string looks looks like in each case? I'm thinking you may be missing a space or another character that you think you are including. I wouldn't think that the nested select would be an issue.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, when I changed the sql back to use the variable, it started working.